# How can I reload .spacemacs file after editing without restart emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs(spacemacs), and I follow [this article](http://thume.ca/howto/2015/03/07/configuring-spacemacs-a-tutorial/) to learn spacemacs.

> Once you are done editing, save the file and either press C-c C-c in the file to reload it or just restart Spacemacs.

But after I save the `.spacemacs` and then press `C-c C-c`, the powerline told me `C-c C-c is undefined`.

How can I reload `.spacemacs` file after editing without restart emacs?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I found the solution: `SPC f e R`

It is from ["Dotfile Configuration" in the Spacemacs Docs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#dotfile-configuration).

Comment: Somehow this doesn't seem to work (I knew the keyboard shortcut already, but it is not working for me) e.g. I have "dotspacemacs-line-numbers t" in dotspacemacs/init  But "SPC f e R" does not reflect the change. Quitting and starting spacemacs works.

Comment: fyi I personally used (global-linum-mode) and (linum-relative-toggle) in my dotspacemacs/user-config to enable (relative) line numbers.  (Just add them like that in the user-config block and reload)

Comment: For those in emacs mode, you can use `M-m f e R`

Comment: That actually works well for me--maybe it works on recent version of spacemacs?

Comment: This does not seem to work if emacs is running in daemon mode.

Comment: is there a way to instruct it not to update melpa while reloading via M-m f e R ?

Answer (score 30):

`SPC f e R` doesn't work for me so I personally use `SPC q R`. It completely restarts spacemacs though - but if you maintain sessions `(dotspacemacs-auto-resume-layouts t)` in config), spacemacs will restart with same buffers. Hope it'll help someone.

`dotspacemacs-auto-resume-layouts` is a config option which can be found in `setq-default` section of your `.spacemacs` file. It comes with default spacemacs setup, it's default value is `nil`.

Comment: Which section/function do you put `(dotspacemacs-auto-resume-layouts t)` into?

Answer (score 7):

For those who work in emacs mode, it might be little difficult to get this done with keybindings. In such case, do `M-X` then type `dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers`

Answer (score 1):

`SPC q r` or `(restart-emacs-resume-layouts)` will restart emacs whilst preserving the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is press space twice (`SPC SPC`) which brings you into the emacs command mode.

Then type: `sync-config` and press Enter which will execute the `dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers` command and reload your config.